# Set of convergent sequences as a vector space, show associativity

Tags: sequences-and-series, vector-spaces

I try to prove that a set of convergent sequences $S=\{(a_n) : (a_n) \text{ convergent sequence of natural numbers} \}$
is a vector space.

I'm guess I have to show that [all 8 axioms are valid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition), but I have a problem how to show the associativity. Should I do it with the epsilon criterion or is enough to say that the + operation on sequences behaves just like it would on the set of real numbers.

Comment: Over which field is supposed to be your "vector space"?

Comment: As the above comment points out, presumably instead of "convergent sequence of natural numbers" you meant to write "convergent sequence of real numbers".

Comment: no the exercise is only for natural numbers

Comment: Then the result is false: (S,+) is not even a group.

Comment: @user48805 why? except for identity i'm pretty sure all the properties are met

Comment: What is the inverse of the sequence $(1,1,1,\ldots)$?

Comment: ok my bad, the members of a sequene can be real numbers; just the indexes should be natural numbers... which is clear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To argue for associativity of addition, your second proposal is correct - there is nothing special about convergence here, and no limit-related argument is necessary. Addition of three non-convergent sequences $(x_n)$, $(y_n)$, and $(z_n)$ is associative for exactly the same reason.

In contrast, showing *closure* under the operations of addition and scalar multiplication requires a (comparatively) non-trivial amount of work. It is possible to add two non-convergent sequences together and get a convergent sequence, so we see that something about convergence must be used.

Answer (score 5):

It might be more natual to show that the set of *all real sequences* is a real vector space -- this vector space really is like $\mathbb{R}^n$ only with coordinates indexed by all positive integes instead of just $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ -- and then show that the convergent sequences form a subspace.  In this case the calculus facts that you need to use are very familiar: e.g. that a sum of two convergent sequences is convergent.

At least this approach makes clear that you will not have to use any "epsilontics" to show the associativity of addtion.

Comment: I see how this could be beneficial. Under the assumption that M ist not empty, how can I show the closure of addition and scalar multiplication?